# Where is Qt 5 Qt3D QCircularBuffer?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, c++17

I would like to try `QCircularBuffer`, as per https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qt3d-qcircularbuffer.html, so I created a simple Qt (5.15.1) project on QtCreator on macOS. It looks like the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

#include <Qt3D>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And in project file I have

```
QT += core gui widgets 3dcore
```

But I cannot build this, I got:

```
18:48:09: Running steps for project project...
18:48:09: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:48:09: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j8
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++1z  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_3DCORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib/Qt3DCore.framework/Headers -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Headers -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -Idebug -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I../../Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/user/Qt5.15.1/5.15.1/clang_64/lib -o debug/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'Qt3D' file not found
#include <Qt3D>
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
18:48:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.1 clang 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.15.1 clang 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

It looks like I'm doing something wrong, right?

Comment: Do you have the 3d module installed?

Comment: I think so because project builds fine with `QT += core gui widgets 3dcore`, if I comment `#include <Qt3D>`.

Comment: It is not a proof, I guess. I am also able to compile a project with QT += 3dcore, although I have not installed this module with Qt.

Comment: To me it looks like this class has been removed from Qt3D. Have you had a look at [`QContiguousCache`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcontiguouscache.html)? It looks as if it has the same capabilities. By the way, I've never seen anyone import Qt3D like you do. I always only import the classes that I need directly.

Comment: What should I import in order to use `QCircularBuffer`? Suppose I'm using that version of Qt which have `QCircularBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

please add QT += 3dcore
to your .pro file of your project.

if error remains, your module “Qt3D.Core” is not installed.
please install it and recompile your project again.

Comment: `QT += 3dcore` is already there, as mentioned in the question. There is no error related to incluing `3dcore`. As I understand, it complains about that `Qt3D`, I'm afraid it doesn't exist anymore in `Qt 5.15.1`